# I want to improve my mysql query though its working fine but need some help to improve

Tags: mysql

```
insert into tbl_orderdetails (package_expiry,package_mocktest, package_section_test, package_video,  order_id, package_name, status,orderdetail_date) 
values                            (
( select package_exp from tbl_package where package_name = get_package_name),
( select package_mocktest_count from tbl_package where package_name = get_package_name),
( select package_section_count from tbl_package where package_name = get_package_name),
( select package_video_count from tbl_package where package_name = get_package_name),
 @orderId, get_package_name, 1, NOW());
```

There are so many select from one table, is there some alternative for this ?
Thank you very much for your efforts and giving me some valuable time to improve me. Sorry for Bad english.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Since I am new to StackOverflow thank you for guiding me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you should use insert select something like this

```
insert into tbl_orderdetails 
(package_expiry,package_mocktest, package_section_test, package_video,  order_id, package_name, status,orderdetail_date) 
select package_exp ,
         package_mocktest_count,
         package_section_count, 
         package_video_count ,
         @orderId, get_package_name, 1, NOW())
from tbl_package where package_name = get_package_name
```

Comment: Thank you That I was looking for